# Unable to check/uncheck checkbox when inside Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using `bootstrap` dropdown along with **ng-repeat** to produce a list but I'm unable to **check** or **uncheck** the `checkbox` inside the div with **data-toggle='dropdown'**.

Checkbox works, when I remove data-toggle='dropdown'.

```
 <div class="dropdown" ng-repeat="item in someArray">
     <div class="dropdown-toggle main-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <input type="checkbox"/>
     {{item}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post a working code example...

Comment: Are you using [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) ?

Comment: It seems to works fine, look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PutJyIPnYDix06OilEyh?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-toggle is capturing the click and stopping propagation to the checkbox.

Move the input before to the div with data-toggle and it will work fine.

```
<div class="dropdown" ng-repeat="item in someArray">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <div class="dropdown-toggle main-title" data-toggle="dropdown">
        item: {{item}}
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```